# while deploying code in local host css class is not working in visual studio

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

i had publish my code in local host but after publishing code my Css classes are not working and page designs are not coming properly while running in local host it is working properly
i am passing css link in my aspx page like

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

and script src is like

```
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried ../bootstrap/css instead of ../../?

Comment: no sir let me check

Comment: Your browser can tell you which files get loaded and which don't.

Comment: sir  my problem is solved out thank you